# Code for detecting flash and html5 in android

Tags: android, html, html5-video

As we know, some android devices can support flash and HTML5. However, not all android devices support HTML5. Can we have some program code like JavaScript to detect whether particular android devices support HTML5?

I'm mostly interested in capabilities concerning video playback.

Comment: You should be explicit that you are not "mostly" interested in video playback, but *only* interested in video playback - otherwise your question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 is an ubrella for many different unrelated technologies. These can be individually supported (or not supported) by any browser. The way to go is [feature detection](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html) to check if the needed technology is present.

Comment: Sorry, some users do not upgrade their android devices from flash to HTML5. If the video only support HTML5, these users would not view the video.

Comment: In case of *web video* the fallback is a given: If you start with a flash player and put your `video` tag *around* the `object` tag representing the flash player the browser will automatically decide which one to use. (If it is capable of HTML5 video then it will be used, the flash will be loaded otherwise).